# How to log every browser console log event

Tags: javascript, browser, console

Is there some event being fired when something is logged to the console? I'd like to take all logs and create a logfile and sed it to the server for debugging.

It is easy with console.log() commands i perform but i need it for unexpected error or warnings too.

Comment: It may be done the same way with `console.error` and `console.warn`. This worked for me in at least FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to catch an actual error, use something like this

```
window.addEventListener('error', onError)
var errors = [];
function onError(message){
    errors.push(message);
}
```

Otherwise, micha's code is great

Comment: Thanks but it also does not work for me. I used your code and caused an error, which shoes up in the console but the "errors" array stays empty. It's wired but i can't see micha's code anymore

Comment: It works now, thanks. It was my fault, i think michas code works too, unfortunately i can't see his post anymore to mark it as the solution